# Nginx Reason for $uri/

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I am looking at standard nginx server config for wordpress.

```
location / {
        
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

*I understand the reason for $uri index.php$is_args$args*

**I do not understand the point of **$uri/****

I can see from nginx documentation  "*It is possible to check directory’s existence by specifying a slash at the end of a name, e.g. “$uri/”*"

But I don`t get, what is the reason for returning a directory on request?  Why would this be useful in a wordpress setup?

Comment: You probably don't need `$uri/` in **every** WordPress installation. But if the WordPress installation has other `index.php` files in subdirectories, the `$uri/` parameter means they can be invoked by using the URI of the subdirectory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "returning a directory on request". But trying to examine contents of a directory, and use them in order to satisfy a request - that's what it is here.

NGINX always has some non-empty value for the [`index`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) directive (default is `index.html`), and that's essentially the files that NGINX will attempt to serve when trying a directory.

You don't *really* need `$uri/` for WordPress if both conditions are met:

- you don't have *custom* subdirectories/subsites which hold PHP files
- you are using pretty permalinks

Removing `$uri/` will result in saving one or more system `stat` calls (file existence check), so it is a performance improvement. The special case there would be a link `/wp-admin`. With `try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args` it will be processed through `/index.php`, but Wordpress will do a proper redirect to `/wp-admin/` (with slash).

And for what it's worth, you [don't even need `try_files`](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-try_files-is-evil-too) if you have a habit of maintaining a well-structured website and intend to make it more optimized.